# Ubuntu freezes after I run video on the full screen on Chrome 40

Tags: video, google-chrome, 14.10, intel-graphics

After the last update, when I run video on a full screen(youtube, facebook video...) the cursor disappears, and the video works well. But when I close the video(with esc) the whole system freezes and I use RESUIB command to restart it. This happened after last chrome update. I use ubuntu 14.10, intel graphics 4000 and stock drivers, because there are no intel drivers for 14.10 yet. This happens aproximatily every second time I run full screen.  Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just disable `Override software rendering list` in `chrome://flags` solves the problem for me!

Comment: Any side effects of doing that?

Comment: Actually, mine already seems to be disabled.

Answer (score 6):

Disabling "Hardware Acceleration" (Settings -> search -> hardware) and restarting chrome solves the problem for now. The problem exists also when you press F11 (full screen).

Comment: This solves the problem for me, thanks! The `Override software rendering list.` option was already disabled.

Comment: This is a workaround, but also has the side effect of disabling WebGL for me.

Answer (score 2):

I have the exact same issue.

Personally, I sent a bug report and decided to downgrade chrome to its previous version.
I did this by first downloading the 39.0.2171.99 version on http://mirror.pcbeta.com/google/chrome/deb/pool/main/g/google-chrome-stable/

Then I made sure to fully exit chrome, and run

```
sudo dpkg -i google-chrome-stable<version>.deb
```

The last thing I had to do was to rename ~/.config/google-chrome else the browser tells you it's using the configuration from a newer version and it can lead to conflicts.

Now we just have to wait until updates.

Comment: Great, I hope there will be a solution.

Comment: Could you give me link so I can view the bug and add myself as affected.

Comment: I linked this thread in the description of the bug so it's already done !

Comment: Ok, I would still like to see it if it's not a problem.

Answer (score 1):

To me this appears to be fixed in the dev build.

```
sudo apt-get install google-chrome-beta
```

This doesn't overwrite your current chrome but adds a new one, so you'll have to go through set up again. Once chrome-stable reaches the same version number as beta, it may be a good idea to return to that too (version 41.0.2272.35).